# Set corner radius of a button programatically in WPF

Tags: wpf

How can I set the corner radius without using any xaml/style tags/resources.

I tried the following:

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(Button));
Setter setter = new Setter(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, new CornerRadius { BottomLeft= 10 , BottomRight = 10 , TopLeft = 10 , TopRight = 10});
style.Setters.Add(setter);

Button.Style = style;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `Border.CornerRadiusProperty` directly in a Button Style has no effect because Button does not have that property.

You would have to add a default Border Style to the Resources of the Button Style, which would affect all possible Border elements in the ControlTemplate of the Button.

```
var borderStyle = new Style(typeof(Border));
borderStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, new CornerRadius(10)));

var buttonStyle = new Style(typeof(Button));
buttonStyle.Resources.Add(typeof(Border), borderStyle);

button.Style = buttonStyle;
```